# Want to know how to make a request to HTTPS appl with Basic Auth enabled

Tags: ssl, basic-authentication, citrus-framework

My application is running on HTTPS. So, I have made 3 citrus-clients that talks to HTTPS Application. I've done similar to **citrus-sample-https**. I'm able to get response from some endpoints that doesn't have Basic Auth enabled. But some other endpoints has Basic-Authentication enabled. 
Similar to :

```
.client().requestFactory( <SSLRequestFactory >)
```

I have referred **citrus-http-basic-auth** sample. Basic-Auth object is also passed to requestFactory() method. How can I achieve both SSL & Basic-Auth?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to only keep using the SSL enabled request factory on the client and add Basic auth header in the test send actions (only for those calls that require Basic auth).

You can add the Basic auth header in your request by doing something like:

```
http().client("sslClient")
    .send()
    .post()
    .header("Authorization", "Basic citrus:encodeBase64('username:password')")
```

You can also use variables for username and password

```
.header("Authorization", "Basic citrus:encodeBase64('${username}:${password}')")
```